# Is the Angular templateCache shared between apps? Is it persistent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have two Angular apps that run on the same domain, will/can they share data in the templateCache? Or is the cache unique to each main application module? In general I'm trying to understand what dictates when a new templateCache is created.

Furthermore I'm not clear on whether or in what way the templateCache is persistent? Looking in local storage and cookies, I don't see where anything is getting stored.

Comment: I believe tempCache is only persistent till you refresh the browser. So it is in-memory.

Comment: no reason can't create a module that contains your templateCache, and inject that module into different apps. Assuming you have them stored within your code, not relying on angular to do caching automatically

Comment: It is surreal and a testament to the hit or miss nature of SO that this question is not upvoted more. This is as important as any other possible design question for AngularJS apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

templateCache is not persisted in any way; it's an in-memory, client-side cache to avoid multiple HTTP requests to fetch the same template URL.

Specifically, it is used by `<script type='text/ng-template'>` to preload templates and by `templateUrl` to cache templates when they are requested multiple times within the same run of the application. Reloading the page creates a new, empty templateCache.

Comment: This matches what i'm observing, and i can't find anything to suggest it does otherwise. Out of curiosity are you basing this on anything in the documentation, or just your own experience?

Comment: @alexp Part personal experience, part checking out the source. I thought the docs mentioned that `$templateCache` was created from [`$cacheFactory`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$cacheFactory), which would make it clearer, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: there is another use case whereby you can `put` templates in templateCache from strings in your script. Can do it within `run()` for any of your modules